# Get ZSH environment variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've set an environment variable in my `~/.zshrc` file and verified that is shows in the terminal with `printenv`:

```
 AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=111111111
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=222222222
 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=AAAAABBBBBBBBB34B3B3B3B3B3B3B3B3B
 STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_1111111111111111
 STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_222222222222222
```

I've also checked that I can get the value in `irb`:

```
 ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
 => "sk_test_222222222222222"
```

However, I'm getting nothing for the value in my Ruby script.  It doesn't return anything.  All I'm running at this point is:

```
 key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
 puts key
```

Which returns a blank space (not `nil`) or anything.

[image: nothing]

What am I missing?

Comment: sudo is the superuser so will have different env variables. The file you're accessing where you set the environment variable is in your home dir? Do it without sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your command with `sudo`, it's possible the user running the script is not your user account (but depending on the system it could be `root`).

Therefore, you need to make sure that the user running the script is actually the one you setup the environment variable for.

Comment: So, it looks like my user shell is `/bin/zsh` whereas my sudo shell is `/bin/sh`, so that would be the problem.  Any clue how to source the sudo `.bashrc` file from zsh (the calling shell)?

Comment: That's a great question! Now, if only there was a website where one could ask basic [su] or [unix.se] questions ;-)